# Uib-Dropdown Does not work in Body of HTML View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-animate

I have installed, correctly, the following:

`"ui-bootstrap": "0.12.2",
    "ngAnimate": "1.5.5",
    "AngularJs": "1.5.5`

When creating a dropdown menu in the body tag of my html view, I am not receiving any visible results. I am not receiving any error messages in both console and network analyzer. Also, all other angularJS and code work perfectly in the view, so there is nothing wrong with external set-up. Here is the HTML in Question:

```
 <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
  <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    DropDown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And Here is JS in Question:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']);
 myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log) {

 $scope.status = {
 isopen: false
 };

$scope.toggled = function(open) {
$log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
};

$scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
$scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
};

$scope.appendToEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#dropdown-long-content'));
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ui-bootstrap 0.14.0, they require the uib- prefix for their directives. It looks like you're using an earlier version so you should get the directive to show by removing the uib- prefix. In other words, "uib-dropdown-menu" becomes "dropdown-menu" etc.

Either that, or use the latest version of ui-bootstrap.

Source: [bootstrap migration guide for prefixes](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes)